# Can I Read a MemoryStream As If It Were a File in C#?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, memorystream

Currently, when dealing with files on SharePoint 2010, they are accessed via WebDav, so they are being opened using a file path instead of a URL - as long as the account has permissions on the file, it can be opened, read from and closed without issue.

Now we are moving all our sites to SharePoint Online, that's no longer possible as WebDav is insecure and it's not enabled so we cannot interact with files in the same way. We have had to write an API (in C#) that allows files to be interacted with on SharePoint Online sites using Graph API for authentication, and currently we are copying them down to a defined location, whether that be a user-defined path, or the user's app data folder where the file can then be opened/read from/relevant content copied to, say, SQL server and then closed, before deleting the local file.

The issue we are having is that some files cannot be saved 'locally' as they contain personal data or other reasons defined by the business, so we were looking to see if we could pass the relevant file read from an online site as a FileStream or MemoryStream, and if that could then be dealt with as if it were a file without the need to save it anywhere, i.e. if it's a CSV file, open and read from the file in memory, write to the, say, SQL server and then dispose of the stream, so the file has never had to reside on a file server somewhere?

I hope that makes sense, any questions, please do ask for clarification.

Many thanks

Martin

Comment: The general answer is yes. The question is whether the target accepts streams as arguments.

Comment: how are you downloading files from SharePoint ?

Comment: @aamd We have written our own API using Graph API which authenticates with our Azure AD and allows access to upload/download files to/from SharePoint Online. This late requirement is borne of other departments wanting to use what we have written but not being involved at the specification/requirement stages.

Comment: @500 - Internal Server Error The intention is to supply them with a file or memory stream, and let them create a target that accepts it - I was just trying to be helpful and share an example of how they might do that, but have not dealt with streams much and didn't want to offer help if it wasn't a workable solution.